# RAM caching of files on disk, based on file extension

Tags: windows, speed, cache, ramdisk

This is what I need: improve access time with small files of specific extension type, by making them pre-loaded in RAM.

I need this to speed up visual studio builds.

Does anybody know of a cache tool that can be configured like that?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this question is a better match for stackoverflow.com (buildsystems ...), but here are my 2 ct:

- just put all the files of your sourcecode into a ramdisk.
- buy ssd, from what i've heard it speeds up build times pretty well
- buy something like [incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/performance_features.htm) which caches compile results, compiles in the grid on multiple machines

and naturally, do all of the above.

at least i am not aware of something in the windows-OS to tell the filesystem - cacher to treat some files differently then others.